# NoSuchMethodError in spark submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-httpasyncclient

I submitted my jar with dependencies to spark using spark-submit. In main method of my jar I want to create `HttpAsyncCliens` instance and execute some request (apache http async client library):

```
val httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom.setMaxConnTotal(10).setMaxConnPerRoute(10).build
httpClient.start()
httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com"), new FutureCallback[HttpResponse] {
    /* callbacks */
})
```

It throws exceptions:

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:315)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:191)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.ensureRunning(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:123)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:74)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:107)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:91)
>           at spark.Application$.main(Application.scala:37)
>           at spark.Application.main(Application.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

It seems like there is no http-core dependency in my jar but I can call this method (`org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V`) in code before or after http client creation and request:

```
org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(true, "test", "test2") // it produces no exception

val httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom.setMaxConnTotal(10).setMaxConnPerRoute(10).build
httpClient.start()
httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com"), new FutureCallback[HttpResponse] {
    /* callbacks */
}) // it produces exception
```

Why I got NoSuchMethodError if I can call this method from same classpath in code?

Apache httpasyncclient v4.1

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to sync up with the version of httpcomponents.httpcore that is in the immediate classpath of spark. For version 1.6 the version is 4.0.1.

You will have to unzip the spark jar to view the META-INF, etc. After some detective work things will be alright!